# How to set multicolumn dropdown as such each drop down will use the same drop down frame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I was required to program the following header ( the borders I've added 
to know if it renders as I need to ):

[image]

"Select Project", "Select Item" and "Select Content" are dropdown elements.
Each one take 2 grids. I need that when clicking on the dropdown element, no matter which one, the drop down menu will take a width of 6 grids as shown above 
in the blue frame. 
( In other words, the drop down menu will be the same for all dropdown elements
  but the content is different ).

In addition, when resizing to smaller screen, the media query doesn't work at all:

```
/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) and (max-width : 1370px) {
  .dropdown-menu.multi-column {
    width: 765px !important;
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

## HTML:

```
<!-- Layout Container-->
<div id="main-wrapper">
  <!--Header - Top Bar Navigation-->
  <header class="margin-left-right-20">
    <div class="row top-bar">
      <!-- Logo Image -->
      <div class="col-md-1 col-lg-1 top-bar-margin-top border-div">
        <img src="images/logo.png" id="logo" alt="logo" />
      </div>

      <!-- Application Indicator -->
      <div class="col-md-1 col-lg-1 top-bar-margin-top border-div">
        <a href="#">
          <div>
            <span class="top-bar-small-title">App</span>
            <br />
            <span class="top-bar-app-links" id="current-app-selected">App1</span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <!-- Module (a.k.a Project) Selector -->
      <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 top-bar-margin-top border-div">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <a id="dLabel" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="top-bar-small-title make-it-regular">Project</span>
            <br />
            <span class="top-bar-app-links make-it-regular">Select Project</span>
            <span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
            <div class="dropdown-menu multi-column">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                  <div class="span6">
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Col 1 - Opt 1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Col 1 - Opt 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="span6">
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Col 2 - Opt 1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Col 2 - Opt 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>






            <!--<li>
                                <div class="row" style="width: 760px;">
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled col-md-4">
                                        <li><a href="#">test1-1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">test1-2</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">test1-3</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled col-md-4">
                                        <li><a href="#">test2-1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">test2-2</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">test2-3</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled col-md-4">
                                        <li><a href="#">test3-1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">test3-2</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">test3-3</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </li>-->





            <!--<li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>-->
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>


      <!-- Module (a.k.a Project) Selector -->
      <!--<div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 top-bar-margin-top border-div">
                    <span class="top-bar-small-title make-it-regular">Module</span><br />
                    <span class="top-bar-app-links make-it-regular">Select Module</span>
                </div>-->


      <!-- Item Selector -->
      <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 top-bar-margin-top border-div">
        <span class="top-bar-small-title make-it-regular">Item</span>
        <br />
        <span class="top-bar-app-links make-it-regular">Select Item</span>
      </div>

      <!-- Block Selector -->
      <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 top-bar-margin-top border-div">
        <span class="top-bar-small-title make-it-regular">Content</span>
        <br />
        <span class="top-bar-app-links make-it-regular">Select Content</span>
      </div>

      <!-- Search Bar -->
      <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-2 top-bar-margin-top border-div" id="div-search-bar">
        <div class="input-group input-search col-md-12 col-lg-12 form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q" id="search-bar" placeholder="Search...">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default btn-search-custom" type="submit">
                                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                            </button>
                        </span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Avatar user -->
      <div class="col-md-1 col-lg-1 top-bar-margin-top border-div" id="div-avatar-circle">
        <div class="avatar-circle col-lg-1">
        </div>
        <div class="show-user col-lg-8" style="display:inline-block">
          <span class="show-user-name">Lionel Messi</span>
          <span class="show-user-permission">Programmer</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End <div class="row top-bar">-->
  </header>
</div>
```

## CSS:

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  /*    height:100%;*/
}

.margin-left-right-20 {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.border-div {
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.container {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#logo {
  width: 79px;
  height: 42px;
  margin-left: 26px;
}

.top-bar {}

.top-bar-margin-top {
  margin-top: 43px;
  /*padding: 0;*/
}

.top-bar-margin-top a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.top-bar-small-title {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #2baab1;
}

.top-bar-app-links {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #2baab1;
}

#current-app-selected {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#search-bar {
  /*width: 325px;*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 29px;
}


/*@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1368px) {
   #search-bar{
    width: 200px;
    height: 29px;
   }
}*/


/*#avatar-and-search-in-new-line {
    display:none;

}*/

.make-it-regular {
  color: #373d42;
}

input.search-query {
  padding-left: 26px;
}

.input-group-btn:last-child {
  border-radius: 500px;
}

.input-search .input-group-btn {
  color: #ccc;
}

.input-group-icon .input-group-btn,
.input-search .input-group-btn {
  border-radius: 500px;
  width: 0;
  left: -13%;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.input-group-btn {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.input-group-addon,
.input-group-btn {
  width: 1%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.input-group-addon,
.input-group-btn,
.input-group .form-control {
  display: table-cell;
}

input-group-rounded input.form-control:first-child,
.input-group-rounded input.form-control:last-child,
.input-search input.form-control:first-child,
.input-search input.form-control:last-child {
  border-radius: 500px;
}

.input-group-icon input.form-control:first-child,
.input-group-icon input.form-control:last-child,
.input-search input.form-control:first-child,
.input-search input.form-control:last-child {
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.input-group .form-control:first-child,
.input-group-addon:first-child,
.input-group-btn:first-child > .btn,
.input-group-btn:first-child > .btn-group > .btn,
.input-group-btn:first-child > .dropdown-toggle,
.input-group-btn:last-child > .btn:not(:last-child):not(.dropdown-toggle),
.input-group-btn:last-child > .btn-group:not(:last-child) > .btn {
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.input-group-rounded input.form-control,
.input-search input.form-control {
  -webkit-border-radius: 500px;
  border-radius: 500px;
}

.input-group-icon input.form-control,
.input-search input.form-control {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding-right: 36px;
}

.input-group-addon,
.input-group-btn,
.input-group .form-control {
  display: table-cell;
}

.input-group .form-control {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="datetime"],
input[type="datetime-local"],
input[type="date"],
input[type="month"],
input[type="time"],
input[type="week"],
input[type="number"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="url"],
input[type="search"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="color"],
textarea {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #555;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
  -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
  transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}

.input-group-btn:first-child,
.input-search .input-group-btn:last-child {
  border-radius: 500px;
}

.input-search .input-group-btn {
  color: #ccc;
}

.input-group-icon .input-group-btn,
.input-search .input-group-btn {
  border-radius: 500px;
  width: 0;
}

.input-group-btn {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.input-group-addon,
.input-group-btn {
  width: 1%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.input-group-addon,
.input-group-btn,
.input-group .form-control {
  display: table-cell;
}

.btn-search-custom {
  border: 0px solid transparent;
  padding: 0;
}

.input-group-btn:last-child>.btn,
.input-group-btn:last-child>.btn-group {
  z-index: 2;
  margin-left: 13px;
}

#div-avatar-circle {
  padding: 0;
}

.avatar-circle {
  background-color: #5c6770;
  border-color: #5c6770;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.show-user {
  display: inline-block;
  /* width: 98px; */
  margin-top: 3px;
  /* margin-left: 10px; */
  /* margin: 0; */
  /* padding: 0px; */
  padding-left: 3px;
}

.nav-tabs-colors {
  background-color: #ececef;
}

.edit-app-tabs {
  background-color: #ececef;
}

#edit-app-tab {
  background-color: #ececef;
}

#edit-app-content-title {
  margin-left: 35px;
}

.app-name-title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 193px;
}

.app-name-title div h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.privacy-statement-text-area {
  position: absolute;
  top: 241px;
}

#privacy-statement-data {
  background-color: white;
  resize: none;
  overflow-y: auto;
  /*width:460px;*/
  height: 224px;
  max-height: 224px;
}

.panel {
  background: transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
}

.panel {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  /*    border-radius: 4px;*/
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  /*    overflow-y: auto;*/
  /*width:431px;*/
  /*width:402px;*/
}

.panel-margin-settings {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#first-component {
  margin-top: 33px;
}

.component-heading {
  background: #2baab1;
  height: 47px;
}

.component-heading-title {
  margin-top: 11px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
}

.panel-heading {
  background: #fdfdfd;
  /*    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;*/
  /*    border-bottom: 1px solid #DADADA;*/
  /*    padding: 18px;*/
  position: relative;
}


/*
.panel-title {
    color: #33353F;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    text-transform: none;
}
*/

.panel-title {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #2baab1;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
}

.panel-heading + .panel-body {
  /*    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;*/
}

.panel-body {
  background: #fdfdfd;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  /*    border-radius: 5px;*/
}

.panel-body {
  padding: 15px;
}

.checkbox-custom {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0 0 25px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.checkbox-custom input[type="checkbox"] {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 3px;
  margin: -6px 0 0 0;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.checkbox-custom label {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

.checkbox-custom label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: -9px;
  width: 19px;
  height: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  background: #fff;
}

.checkbox-custom input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  content: '\F00C';
  top: 50%;
  left: 4px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 1;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  color: #2baab1;
}

.checkbox-inline {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*
.checkbox-inline input[type="checkbox"] {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -20px;
}

*/

.new-category {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.new-category:link,
.new-category:visited,
.new-category:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dd {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /*    list-style: none;*/
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.dd-list {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: decimal;
  /*    list-style: none;*/
}

.dd-item,
.dd-empty,
.dd-placeholder {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 20px;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: list-item;
}

.dd-item-reset {
  font-size: 0;
}

.dd-handle {
  display: block;
  height: 34px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  background: white;
  /*    background: #F6F6F6;*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.dd-list-ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.dd-handle-assoc-file {
  display: inline-block;
  /*width:280px;*/
  width: 277px;
  height: 31px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.btn-associated-file-item {
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-color: #5c6770;
  border-style: solid;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-width: 1px;
  height: 31px;
  width: 93px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  /*    border-right:1px solid blc;*/
}

.close-assoc-file {
  line-height: inherit;
}

#glossary-file-select,
#definition-file-select,
#design-file-select {
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: -1000;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

#modules-list-table-padding {
  padding-left: 65px;
  padding-right: 65px;
}

#modules-list-table-title {
  margin-top: 33px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  display: block;
}

#create-module {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #2baab1;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inherit;
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#table-underline {
  border: 1px solid #2baab1;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

.modules-table > tbody > tr > th,
.modules-table > tbody > tr > td {
  border-color: #ececef;
}

.modules-table tr > *:nth-child(1) {
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.modules-table tr > *:nth-child(2) {
  padding-left: 67px;
  width: 336px;
  max-width: 336px;
}

.modules-table tr > *:nth-child(3) {
  padding-left: 103px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.modules-table tr > *:nth-child(4) {
  padding-right: 11px;
}

.modules-table > tbody > tr > td:last-child {
  text-align: center;
}


/*.modules-table tr > th:last-child {
    padding-right: initial;
    float:right;
}*/


/*.modules-table tr > *:last-child {
    padding-left: 10px;
}*/


/*.modules-table  > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) {
    width:336px;
}*/


/*div[class^="col-lg-1"]:first-child {
    margin-left: 20px;
}*/


/*div[class^="col-lg-1"]:last-child {
    margin-right: 20px;
}


div[class^="col-lg-3"]:first-child {
    margin-left: 20px;
}

div[class^="col-lg-3"]:last-child {
    margin-right: 20px;
}*/

.tools-option-link {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: #373d42;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.tools-option-container {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px black;
}

.reset-padding-top {
  padding-top: 0;
}

#tools-block a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#ChartistExtremeResponsiveConfiguration {}

.module-name {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
}

.circular-bar.circular-bar-xs {
  width: 50px;
}

.circular-bar {
  margin: 25px 0;
}

.circular-bar {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.mr-md {
  margin-right: 15px !important;
}

.mt-xs {
  margin-top: 5px !important;
}

.m-none {
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.circular-bar-container {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
}

.circular-bar-percentage-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 29%;
  left: 21%;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#module-of-the-day-id {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: #2baab1;
}

#module-of-the-day-name {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: #373d42;
}

.stars-styling {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #ffbb00;
}

#module-of-the-day-review-paragraph {
  /*width:343px;*/
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

#item-reviewer {
  float: right;
  font-size: 14px;
  /*font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;*/
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #373d42;
}

#module-of-the-day-item-reviewer {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#module-usage-stats {
  clear: both;
}

#module-usage-description {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px black;
}

#module-usage-text-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13%;
}

#module-usage-title {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 5px !important;
}

#module-usage-status {
  font-size: 14px;
}


/* */

#published-items-description {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px black;
}

#published-items-text-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13%;
}

#published-items-title {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 5px !important;
}

#published-items-status {
  font-size: 14px;
}

#published-items-percentage-text {
  top: 33%;
  left: 31%;
}


/* */

#device-description {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px black;
}

#device-text-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3%;
}

#device-title {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 5px !important;
}

#device-status {
  font-size: 14px;
}

#view-all-statistics {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

#view-all-statistics a:link {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.stats-paragraph-styling {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
}

.mb-none {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.text-weight-bold {
  font-weight: 700;
}

h4,
.h4 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}

.text-xs {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.text-muted {
  color: #777;
}


/* */

.general-data-num-styling {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #2baab1;
}

.general-data-text-styling {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #373d42;
}

#items-num-inner-container {
  /*margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;*/
  border-left: solid 1px;
  border-right: solid 1px;
}


/* */

.widget-summary {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.widget-summary .widget-summary-col.widget-summary-col-icon {
  width: 1%;
}

.widget-summary .widget-summary-col {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
}

.widget-summary .summary-icon {
  margin-right: 15px;
  font-size: 42px;
  /*font-size: 4.2rem;*/
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  line-height: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 55px;
  border-radius: 55px;
}

.bg-primary {
  background: #0088cc;
}

.bg-secondary {
  background: #E36159;
  color: #FFF;
}

.bg-tertiary {
  background: #2BAAB1;
  color: #FFF;
}

.bg-quartenary {
  background: #734BA9;
  color: #FFF;
}

.widget-summary .summary {
  min-height: 65px;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.widget-summary .summary .title {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  /*font-size: 1.6rem;*/
  line-height: 22px;
  /*line-height: 2.2rem;*/
  color: #333;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.widget-summary .summary .info {
  font-size: 14px;
  /*font-size: 1.4rem;*/
  line-height: 30px;
  /*line-height: 3rem;*/
}

.widget-summary .summary .amount {
  margin-right: .2em;
  font-size: 24px;
  /*font-size: 2.4rem;*/
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #333;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.widget-summary .summary .info span {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.text-primary {
  color: #0088cc !important;
}

.widget-summary .summary-footer {
  padding: 5px 0 0;
  border-top: 1px dotted #ddd;
  text-align: right;
}

.text-uppercase {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}


/*.panel-featured-tertiary {
    border-color: #2BAAB1;
}

.panel-featured-quartenary {
    border-color: #734BA9;
}*/


/*.panel-featured-left {
    border-left: 3px solid #33353F;
}*/

.module-subscriptions {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 9px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: solid 3px;
}

.dropdown-menu.multi-column {
  width: 1036px;
}

.dropdown-menu.multi-column .dropdown-menu {
  display: block !important;
  position: static !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  border: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  min-width: 100px;
}
```

JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/jaeedxpw/2/

Thanks in advance,
Eli Van Rock

Comment: What you have is very messy. If I were you, i'd start over from scratch. The example you provided doesn't work when you click any of the dropdown menu items. Hard for anyone to give feedback when nothing simply works but ideally if I were you, I'd be doing onClick for the menu items to display the multi-column dropdown.

Comment: Hi Derek, That's the thing. What I've implemented works on my station but still I have the issue of the spanning grids.  The code is maybe long because of the css but the scenario is very simple:

I have 3 drop downs and I was required that when you click on each of the drop-down element, the window of the drop-down content will be spanned by all grids of all drop down elements.

For Example: If I have '''Select Project", "Select Item" and "Select Content" as dropdown elements and each one takes 2 grids, I need that the drop down window will take the whole 6 grids for each one of them

Comment: Seems a bit confusing to be honest with you, especially from a user experience perspective. How does this type of navigation help users get from point A to point B? I believe you could get the effect by using a more traditional drop down menu.

Comment: Unfortunately I have tried using the traditional drop down menu and it didn't help. It's a strange requirement but I was ordered by my boss to do so. Before I will tell him that it cannot be implemented I'll be glad if you have answer for it. If something is not understood for what I've written, please let know.

Comment: yes, I understand. You have to educate the person in charge. You cannot simply take orders because it's something that he wants without having any type of analytical data backing the decision. The best case here is to use a real-world example with your boss and what I use all the time is "would you tell your mechanic how to fix your car?" absolutely not, he has to let you do your job and right now that doesn't seem to be the case here.

What you want is achievable but the example you provided is a bit messy to work with. I'll see if I can give you some pointers soon.

Comment: Thank you very much Derek! I really appreciate it!